# Hazelcast settings in external folder

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

I'm trying to start hazelcast with a non default hazelcast.xml settings.

According to their documentation : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-hazelcast

I've added the -Dhazelcast.config value in my command :
*java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true **-Dhazelcast.config=/opt/hazelcast/config/server/hazelcast.xml** -cp /opt/m2repo/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.6/hazelcast-all-3.6.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp*

The problem is when i run  the command, it does not take my settings into account, but try to find it in the current folder.

So, if i am in /home/alexandre/ it says :
*com.hazelcast.config.FileSystemXmlConfig
INFOS: Configuring Hazelcast from '/home/alexandre/hazelcast.xml'.*

When i run the command from the folder where i put my hazelcast.xml, that's ok. (But not working like i want to)

Thanks in advance for your help!
Alexandre.

Comment: Can you add some more logging? Are you sure you're starting the ConsoleApp and not the server?

Comment: Hello, my aim was to start an hazelcast instance using my specific settings.xml. So finally i got it using com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer instead of com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Finally i got it.

By reading the source code of the com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp
I see it can not work, as it only read local file :

> try {
>       config = new FileSystemXmlConfig("hazelcast.xml"); } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>       config = new Config(); }

So i have downloaded the full hazelcast.tar and looked their /bin/start.sh command, it use ***com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer***

So i have updated my command and it works now :
*java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhazelcast.config=/opt/hazelcast/config/server/hazelcast.xml -cp /opt/m2repo/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.6/hazelcast-all-3.6.jar **com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer***